# Sharepoint 2019 & Visual Studio 2019 Community Content Types & Lists

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2019

[[image: [enter image description here][1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxzJP.png)[![enter image description here]
[![enter image description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ0nA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ0nA.png)
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm relatively new to Sharepoint Dev stuff so bare with me as my question could be part ignorance which I apologise in advance.

I've create a simple List from an example straight off the MS Website using Visual Studio.

The list contains a 3 fields and a single content type which is then deployed to my Test Sharepoint 2019 environment.

Everything appears to deploy as it should and I can create new records from the list on my Sharepoint site etc.

When I created a New Item for my list using the New Item Form shown in my picture a single Field called Patient ID is missing from the form, however it is viewable in the List view. I don't seem to understand where it gets this behaviour from as I've tried everything to have the New Item list view look the same as the standard list view.

Can someone enlighten me please.

If any other information is helpful please let me know and I'll post it.

Thanks

James

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ContentType ID="0x01060094623F738CE64604AD342460E6728AC3" Name="PatientInfo" Group="$Resources:core,List_Content_Types;" Description="Patient information card" Inherits="TRUE" Version="0"><FieldRefs><FieldRef ID="{2b1eb2d2-6346-4e0c-ad88-646abddee7e6}" DisplayName="Patient ID" Required="TRUE" Name="PatientID" Hidden="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInFileDlg="TRUE" ShowInListSettings="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" /></FieldRefs></ContentType></ContentTypes>
<Fields>

<Field ID="{2b1eb2d2-6346-4e0c-ad88-646abddee7e6}" Name="PatientID" DisplayName="Patient ID" Type="Integer" Required="TRUE" Group="Clinic Site Columns" Hidden="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE"></Field></Fields>
<Views>


<View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>

    <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu"></FieldRef></ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>

      <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef></OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_ONET_HOME)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View><View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=23" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>

    <FieldRef Name="PatientID" /></ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>

      <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef></OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View></Views>
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
```

Answer (score 0):

Patient ID is probably not associated to the same content type.
Did you use content types in your list? in list settings, you can have more details on your fields association

some fields are associated to your list, other to your content type

in your "New" Button, how many content types are displayed?
[image]

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. I will check on your suggestion and get back to you. I did use a content type in my list and I believe that this field is in there. I’ll post some more screenshots and the CAML shortly. Perhaps you’ll see something I’m not picking up on.

Comment: Hi @FredericDietrich I have some additional screenshot and code samples. Hope to figure out whats going on here.

Comment: in your list we can see patientId, PatientName, Doctor, Comments so 4 fields, but in your content type we only see PatientID, on your first screen shoot with list columns, click on contentType button, and add missing fields

Comment: after your last message I've gone and done the following 1. Removed/Recreate My site 2. Removed all fields from my Content Type except for Patient ID 3. Recreated my List with my Custom Content Type 4. Deployed My Solution and Activated the Feature. I successfully achieved nothing but more confusion. First, My List only now has Patient ID (this is good what I expected) however when I select New Item you can see the form contains fields I have never even added. Where does it get this from? I'll post screenshot and the CAML.

Comment: You want to add patientID in contentType patientInfo??

Comment: Correct. However I have already done this. What I am driving at is why does Patient ID appear in my list but when I click add new record the form for a new record contains fields that I have not added. They are not in my content type in fact I’m really not sure where they are coming from.

Comment: you should add all your required fields in your target content type

Comment: In this example the only column I added to my content type was shown in the screenshot is patient ID. This is the only column I’d expect to be shown when adding a new record. Instead there are other fields other than what I added to my content type. I’m trying to understand where these are other fields are coming from if I haven’t added them to my content type.